# Table: PrintMgmtSettings Field: Printjobsettings(Blob)

Tags: x++, axapta

### how can i convert the blob in the Field PrintJobSettings to String ?

```
PrintMgmtSettings   rst;
container con = connull();
str     vcon;
;

while select rst
{
    con = rst.PrintJobSettings;
    if (conlen(con)==1)
    {
        print conlen(con);
        print conpeek(con,1);
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific with your needs. This container is probably a serialized (packed) instance of a `PrintJobSettings` class that you can unpack to instantiate a `PrintJobSettings` object that you can use in your code.

If you can specify what is your whole problem will be easier to find a solution.

Comment: i want to print for example an invoice from AX2012 with an ActiveX-RTF Object,therefore i need all detailed Invoice-Printsettings, which are already set,but the printsettings are not available to direct access in tablefields, because they are packed, so my problem is how can i get Invoice-Printersettings from the blob.

Comment: OK then I would try PrintJobSettings.unpackPrintJobSettings method. Take a look to the code on this page (comments are in spanish but X++ is self explaining): http://www.trucosax.com/phpnuke/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&p=7095&NSNST_Flood=ab5833a5f9eee38ff24a0ef857702980

Comment: Also you can instantiate a PJS object fromt he container this way:  printJobSettings = new PrintJobSettings(packedPrintJobSettingsContainer);

Answer (score 0):

To convert a container to string use [con2str](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa643695%28v=ax.50%29.aspx):

```
info(con2str(rst.PrintJobSettings));
```

This is unlikely to be of *any* practical use.